# Width of a flex item should be smaller when text wraps inside the item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to place an icon next to a text in a heading, which should always be in the first line directly next to the text. This works well using flexboxes as long as the text doesn't wrap. If it wraps, the space of the text flex item uses up the rest of the available space, moving the icon to the very right of the heading container.

For example:

```html
<h4 class="example-1">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
    <img class="arrow-button" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/5154/hand-pointer.svg" />
</h4>

<h4 class="example-2">
    <span>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
    <img class="arrow-button" src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/5154/hand-pointer.svg" />
</h4>

<style>
h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 500;

    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 16px;
    
    background: #b5fffb;
}

.example-1 {
  max-width: 220px;
}

.example-2 {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.arrow-button {
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    z-index: 10;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
</style>
```

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mwnxs35r/13/

[image]

How can I make it work so that there isn't so much white space, so that the span only has the width of the text inside?

Comment: Basically you can't. That's the way wrapping happens.